# Magnetic Field at a point in the plane of a current carrying ring

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I wanted to know how exactly we would approach this problem, i.e. how we could find magnetic field at a point in the plane of a current carrying ring both within the radius and outside. Since Ampere's Circuital Law isn't very helpful here (the line integral ends up as zero), I tried using Biot-Savart's Law but I had no idea how to choose the element for integration. I could really use a hint to solve this problem.

Comment: Without writing out what you've tried it's hard to help you, also amperes law does not result in a zero here for the line integral with a proper loop ( you haven't shown the amperian loop you've used anyways). But it's less useful because you need to add the contribution of the entire loop.

Comment: I'm ready to offer an answer to help nudge you in the right direction, but you really need to improve your question.  Give us at least a diagramme of the situation you're talking about so we can apply the correct equation to it. Also, point out on the diagramme what the problem states as your givens and what it wants you to find: your unknowns. If someone never taught you to approach a problem in this way, then it's understandable that you're having trouble. I'll be waiting to help you.

Comment: The necessary computation is explained in this paper - [Off Axis Magnetic Field of a Circular Current Loop](https://www.grant-trebbin.com/2012/04/off-axis-magnetic-field-of-circular.html)